# Get url parameters for a url with '#' instead of '?' in Spring boot GET controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot project, I have a controller which is called from an external url.

```
@GetMapping("/my_controller")
public ModelAndView controller(HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

Generally, the external url is like:

```
http://localhost:8080/my_controller?code=ABC&state=ON
```

However, due to a recent changes the external url has # instead of ?

```
http://localhost:8080/my_controller#code=ABC&state=O
```

As a result I am not able to retrieve the parameters anymore inside my controller. So, is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: No way to do that, because the *fragment* value after the `#` is handled by the web browser and never sent to the server.

Comment: Request can be made not only from browser, but and with any http-client.